# How to log events from a background thread when my app is closed?

Tags: android, multithreading, logging

In my app I am doing certain tasks in a background thread(`ExecutorService` to be precise). This is working fine. However, I want to make sure that when the user closes the app, the task continues to run and finishes its job. In order to know this, I need some way to know whether the task finished after closing the app or not?

I tried using `android.util.Log` class to log certain events on app close, but I don't see the events logging. I also tried using Toast message but that doesn't work too. I was expecting to get a `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` exception since I called the Toast message from the background thread but that didn't happen either, nothing happened.

I am not able to know for sure, if my task ends, which it shouldn't since it runs on a background `ExecutorService` or if these methods won't work when the app is closed? What should I do to log certain events to debug my app when it is closed and events are running in a background thread? Thanks!!